# Differentiating url with Path parameters

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

We are working on a REST based service and we are using Spring MVC for the same. We are facing a url to method resolution problem. This is roughly what we are trying to do

Suppose we have persons with their pets

```
//Class level request mapping
@RequestMapping("/persons")

// Mapping to access a specific person inside one of the methods
@RequestMapping(value="/{personId}", method= RequestMethod.GET
//.... getPerson method


// Mapping to access a specific person's pets inside one of the methods
@RequestMapping(value="/{personId}/pets", method= RequestMethod.GET
// getPersonPets method
```

If the request comes as "/persons/P12323233" where P12323233 is person id, it resolves to the getPerson method.
If the request comes as "/persons/P12323233/pets" where P12323233 is person id, it resolves to the getPersonPets method.

So everything is fine till now. But
If the request comes as "/persons/pets, the request resolves to the getPerson method. While we can handle this as an error case inside in the getPerson method, we are trying to check whether there is anyway of resolving this call to getPersonPets method.

We are still debating whether the right place to handle this case is getPerson or getPersonPets method. That debate aside, we wanted to know whether it is even technical feasible to achieve resolution to the getPersonPets method.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: The URL clearly maps to the first method. So if `"pets"` is an existing ID of a person, it should return this person. If it's not, it should return a 404 Not Found error. Calling `getPersonPets()` doesn't make much sense, and you won't be able to return anything useful anyway, since you don't have any ID of person to find the pets. I would close the debate immediately :)

Comment: It makes sense that when there is a url /persons/pets it will try to invoke the first method and will try to find person with id "pets". if it doesn't find, it will give 404. Second method will never be executed in this case. Thnx for the valuable input.

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved by adding multiple mappings for the same method:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/{personId}", method= RequestMethod.GET
//.... getPerson method

@RequestMapping(value = {"/{personId}/pets", "/pets"}, method= RequestMethod.GET
// getPersonPets method
```

**Update:**
Notice that using the following signature will throw an exception when accessing */pets* as the *personId* is not present in the URL:

```
public String showPets(@PathVariable("personId") long personId)
```

This would be the most convenient way to access the variable, but given we have multiple paths mapped the same method, we could change the signature to the following in order to avoid getting the exception:

```
public String showPets(@PathVariable Map<String, String> vars)
```

And retrieve the path variable from the map

Comment: Using multipe mapping it resolved the problem of going into wrong methods. But when I tried invoking /persons/pets, it gave me a spring exception saying the path variable not provided.

Comment: Right, if you explicitly define the path variable name in the annotation, you get an exception when it's not present in the URL. You can change your signature method to:
    public String showPets(@PathVariable Map<String, String> vars){...}
and obtain the path variable from the map

Answer (score 1):

You could also use regex and filter out such request as 404. For example:

```
// Mapping to access a specific person inside one of the methods
@RequestMapping(value="/{personId:P[\\d]+}", method= RequestMethod.GET
//.... getPerson method


// Mapping to access a specific person's pets inside one of the methods
@RequestMapping(value="/{personId:P[\\d]+}/pets", method= RequestMethod.GET
// getPersonPets method
```

Comment: I have tried doing it using regex. When /persons/pets invoked..it didn't invoke the first method but it gave an error saying http 404 requested resource not found.

Comment: If you're saying it's ok to have /persons/pet, then you're correct, these mappings will not work. So /persons/pet/pets is possible? The regex is based your question and the assumption that a person id is of the form P######.., which in that case then /persons/pet is not valid mapping and would return a 404.

Answer (score 0):

Although generally REST assumes you are referencing an ID when you are not specifying the segment on the resource, I like adding id, to make the rest endpoint less ambiguous.

Consider doing the following if you are allowed to change the API:

```
//Class level request mapping
@RequestMapping("/persons")

// Mapping to access a specific person inside one of the methods
@RequestMapping(value="/id/{personId}", method= RequestMethod.GET
//.... getPerson method


// Mapping to access a specific person's pets inside one of the methods
@RequestMapping(value="/id/{personId}/pets", method= RequestMethod.GET
// getPersonPets method
```